# Updating cart based on values of multiple select tags in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I've implemented a cart in Rails so that when showing said cart, the quantity of each item is displayed as a select tag to allow users to change quantities (the way Amazon does it.) This is how I generate the select tags, which I do for every `item` in the cart:

```
<%= form_for :session, url: update_cart_path, html: { method: 'post'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :quantity_updated,
               options_for_select((1..item.quantity).to_a, quantity),
               {} ,{id: "quantity_select_#{item_id}"} %>
<% end %>
```

This is my JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready ->
$("#quantity_select").change ->
    $.ajax "update_cart",
        method: "POST",
        data: {quantityUpdated: $("#quantity_select option:selected").val()},
        dataType: "script",
        error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
            console.log("AJAX error: #{textStatus}")
        success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
            console.log("AJAX OK")
```

Every `item` in `Cart` has an `item_id`. In order to have unique ids for every item's quantity select tag, I changed `{id: "quantity_select"}` to `{id: "quantity_select_#{item_id}"}`. What do i have to change in the JavaScript file so that every select_tag change is handled properly? And how do I send the `item_id` to the controller? I've tried `url: update_cart_path(item_id: item_id)` but that didn't work. I've also tried `$.ajax "update_cart(#{item_id})` and that didn't work either. Right now the controller has no idea which item's quantity was changed.

Comment: Do you have multiple `$("#quantity_select")` ? You can't have multiple elements with same ID...

Comment: I changed that to `$("#quantity_select_#{item_id}")`.

Comment: Can you edit your questions so we can see the code as you are running it?

Comment: Done. This doesn't run though, because there is no `quantity_select` tag at this point.

Comment: I'm talking about the second line of your JS code. You're only binding to the `$('#quantity_select')` not to every one. Maybe you need to assign a class selecter and use `$('form').on('change','.quantity_select',function() {etc.} );` ? Then you could send the id from inside that function with `$(this).attr('id')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to append #{item.id} to all select tags. just add class `quantity_select`. then in your javascript

```
$('.quantity_select').change({ 
  /* your code */
});
```

also. getting the value of select tag is not from the selected:option. but:

```
$('#quantity_select').val()
```

note ==================================================================
since the value you are trying get is from the selector that was changed. this should be referred as `$(this).val()` within the script block.

last comment I want to make is avoid using double quotes `"` when you code in rails. with double quotes, by default, rails will think it contains a value to parse. like #{val}. if you are not including parse value, just use `'`

Comment: Is there any way I can get the `id` of the `.quantity_select` element that was changed? I tried `$(this).id` and `$(".quantity_select").id`, and neither worked.

Comment: Also, this didn't solve the problem. When I change a selector, i don't get the value form that selector. Binding the change function to a class might not be the best way to do this.

Comment: not being able get the value inside function is I assume you called it exactly as I answered? I will update answer.
      Getting the id is `$('.quantity_select').attr('id')`
and for this too. within the block it should be `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: Right now I have `data: {quantityUpdated: $(this).val(), id: $(this).attr('id').substring(1,5) }` and it doesn't work.

Comment: your end result in developer's console should be somewhat like this. https://jsfiddle.net/57yjq70q/